# How to Reference Json2.js

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

Dear All im getting error like

```
Cannot find JSON.stringify()
```

Some browsers (e.g., IE < 8) don't support it natively, but you can overcome this by adding a script reference to json2.js, downloadable from http://www.json.org/json2.js

/// Script

```
stringifyJson: function (data, replacer, space) {   // replacer and space are optional
            if ((typeof JSON == "undefined") || (typeof JSON.stringify == "undefined"))
                throw new Error("Cannot find JSON.stringify(). Some browsers (e.g., IE < 8) don't support it natively, but you can overcome this by adding a script reference to json2.js, downloadable from http://www.json.org/json2.js");
            return JSON.stringify(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(data), replacer, space);
        },
```

How to refer `json2.js` into my asp.net project?

Answer (score 1):

The most straight forward method would be to install it via a nuget package:

`Install-Package json2`

http://nuget.org/packages/json2

And then add a reference to it in a page/masterpage:

`<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/json2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>`

(Taken from MVC so might require some modification for webforms)

Answer (score 0):

you have to add the json2min.js in your project and then reference in your ASP.NET. it will check whether the browser supports JSON natively, if not then it will call the json2min.js otherwise it won't effect anything.